# Probability distribution and the function for a potential loss of a Pareto r.v.

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let's say X indicates potential loss and has a Pareto density of $f(x)=\frac{ac^a}{x^{a+1}}$ for $x \geq c$, $a>0$, $c>0$.

Consider an insurance policy in which the insured has to take care of the portion below $d>c>0$ of X (deductible) and the insurer only takes care of the portion below $l > d$ of X (coverage limit).

What is the probability distribution $μ_X$ and probability distribution function $F_X$ of the potential loss of **the insured**? The part I am confused about is that:

1. Isn't $\mu_X$ same as the $f(x)$?
2. How should we define $A$? If we define it as $A=[c,\inf)$ it would equal 1.

I have in my notes that *a r.v. $X$ or its probability distribution $μ$ is said to have a density $f$ w.r.t. Lebesgue measure if $f(x) ≥ 0$ is a Borel function on $R$ such that* $$\mu_X=P(x\in A)=\int_Af(x)dx$$.

Also, this question might be helpful to look at: [Induced distribution measure and induced distribution function where original r.v. is Pareto](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2520147/induced-distribution-measure-and-induced-distribution-function-where-original-r)